# Code Contracts for Windows Phone Device

Tags: windows-phone-8, code-contracts

I use Code Contracts in my code, my app runs fine on the emulator. When I deploy it on a device, it fails/crashes whenever Contract statement is executed.

```
 public static HTTPRequest CreateGetRequest(string url,
                                        bool shouldUseCustomTimeout)
        {
            // preconditions
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url));

            return new HTTPRequest(url,
                                    System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get,
                                    shouldUseCustomTimeout);
        }
```

Is the code contract supported on actual device? Should I install a separate extension?

Comment: a quick search led me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972781/code-contracts-not-working-in-windows-phone-8-unit-test

Comment: @LeeGary - that's actually subtly different. This question is about whether this works on a device.

Comment: @LeeGary I have already installed Code Contracts for .Net and vs2012 extension. My unit tests work, but when I deploy my app on a device, it fails/crashes when it executes Contract statements.

Comment: You'll need to provide some error information here. What stacktrace does it crash with? Did you enable runtime contracts, or just static analytics? etc.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen There was no stack trace available, the control goes to unknown location when the app executes contract statements. I set up the project similar to this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/01/simple-and-easy-code-contracts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by following the steps on this blog: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/01/simple-and-easy-code-contracts.html

It turns out that I had to enable for the library projects too. I was setting code contracts only for the test app.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the code contract supported on actual device?

Yes.